# Application not saving logs to specific appender

Tags: java, logging, logback, apache-commons-logging, james

I'm trying to save some logs from Apache James to specific appender.

Apache James by default uses Apache Commons Logging with added Logback. Logback.xml configuration looks like:

```
    <contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
            <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
    </contextListener>

    <!--  Appenders for console and logs -->

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <encoder>
                    <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %highlight([%-5level]) %thread %logger{15}:%line - %msg%n%rEx</pattern>
                    <immediateFlush>false</immediateFlush>
            </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="JAMES" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>./logs/james.log</file>
            <encoder>
                    <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] %thread %logger{15}:%line - %msg%n%rEx</pattern>
                    <immediateFlush>false</immediateFlush>
            </encoder>

            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">       
               <fileNamePattern>./logs/james.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
               <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

<appender name="JAMES-SERVER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>./logs/james-server.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] %thread %logger{15}:%line - %msg%n%rEx</pattern>
        <immediateFlush>false</immediateFlush>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>./logs/james-server.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

    <logger name="org.domain.mypackage" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="JAMES-SERVER" />
    </logger>

    <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
            <appender-ref ref="JAMES"/>
    </root>
```

Apache James starting as

```
java -classpath "james-server-jpa-guice.jar:james-server-jpa-guice.lib/*:james-server-jpa-guice.lib" -javaagent:james-server-jpa-guice.lib/openjpa-3.0.0.jar -Dlogback.configurationFile=./conf/logback.xml -Dworking.directory=. org.apache.james.JPAJamesServerMain >> ./logs/james.log
```

All logs fine to `james.log` but specific package above `org.domain.mypackage` is not logged to `james-server.log` but appears to be in `james.log`

Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Seems you are missing the`additivity` attribute: `<logger name="org.domain.mypackage" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">`

Comment: @LuisMuñoz I have added `additivity` to the related line and it makes that logs from that package are not getting logged in the `james.log` but still are not in the `james-server.log`. Thoughts?

Comment: Permissions on that file? May be its already an empty one and belongs to root or other user, remove it. Also, I don't think you need to add ` >> ./logs/james.log` to the command since you already have a file appender  assigned to `root` log level. You may have duplicated messages.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz I have replaced `james.log` to `james-server.log` in the JAMES appender and it writes to that file so no permission issues. Then I have removed `>> ./logs/james.log` but after that will not log James core code logs - just mailet logs. My goal is to separate James core code as james.log and maliets code logs as james-server.log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup might need 2 fixes, remove `immediateFlush` tags at least for testing and add `JAMES-APPENDER`to `root` logger. `immediateFlush=false` should be set when heavy logging activity is expected, for testing purposes, set it to `true`.

```
  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <appender-ref ref="JAMES" />
    <appender-ref ref="JAMES-SERVER" />
  </root>
```

Logback setup can be conveniently tested using [logback-examples](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-examples/1.1.3) package as follows:

```
export LOGBACK_CP="/home/luis.munoz/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.1/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/home/luis.munoz/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.3/logback-core-1.1.3.jar:logback-examples-1.1.3.jar:/home/luis.munoz/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.3/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar"

java -cp "$LOGBACK_CP" chapters.appenders.ConfigurationTester ~/tmp/logback.xml
```

The following messages will be written to console and any configured files

```
12:37:45.336 [DEBUG] main c.a.ConfigurationTester:50 - **Hello test 123
12:37:45.338 [DEBUG] main c.a.ConfigurationTester:54 - logging statement 0
12:37:45.439 [DEBUG] main c.a.ConfigurationTester:54 - logging statement 1
12:37:45.540 [DEBUG] main c.a.ConfigurationTester:54 - logging statement 2
12:37:45.640 [DEBUG] main c.a.ConfigurationTester:54 - logging statement 3
12:37:45.742 [DEBUG] main c.a.ConfigurationTester:54 - logging statement 4
12:37:45.843 [DEBUG] main c.a.ConfigurationTester:54 - logging statement 5
12:37:45.943 [DEBUG] main c.a.ConfigurationTester:54 - logging statement 6
12:37:46.044 [DEBUG] main c.a.ConfigurationTester:54 - logging statement 7
12:37:46.145 [DEBUG] main c.a.ConfigurationTester:54 - logging statement 8
12:37:46.246 [DEBUG] main c.a.ConfigurationTester:54 - logging statement 9
12:37:46.355 [ERROR] main c.a.s.s.Bar:32 - error-level request
java.lang.Exception: test exception
        at chapters.appenders.sub.sample.Bar.subMethodToCreateRequest(Bar.java:32) [logback-examples-1.1.3.jar:na]
        at chapters.appenders.sub.sample.Bar.createLoggingRequest(Bar.java:27) [logback-examples-1.1.3.jar:na]
        at chapters.appenders.ConfigurationTester.main(ConfigurationTester.java:58) [logback-examples-1.1.3.jar:na]
```

On console, several log records useful for debugging a configuration are written

```
...
12:37:45,333 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [CONSOLE] to Logger[ROOT]
12:37:45,333 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [JAMES] to Logger[ROOT]
12:37:45,333 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [JAMES-SERVER] to Logger[ROOT]
 ...
```

Also, this example package allows to "play" with the configuration and check the result. For example:

```
  <logger name="chapters.appenders.ConfigurationTester" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="JAMES" />
  </logger>

  <logger name="chapters.appenders.sub.sample" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="JAMES-SERVER" />
  </logger>

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
  </root>
```

Will log this to james.log

```
16:04:44.487 [DEBUG] main c.a.ConfigurationTester:50 - **Hello test 123
16:04:44.490 [DEBUG] main c.a.ConfigurationTester:54 - logging statement 0
16:04:44.590 [DEBUG] main c.a.ConfigurationTester:54 - logging statement 1
16:04:44.691 [DEBUG] main c.a.ConfigurationTester:54 - logging statement 2
16:04:44.792 [DEBUG] main c.a.ConfigurationTester:54 - logging statement 3
16:04:44.892 [DEBUG] main c.a.ConfigurationTester:54 - logging statement 4
16:04:44.993 [DEBUG] main c.a.ConfigurationTester:54 - logging statement 5
16:04:45.093 [DEBUG] main c.a.ConfigurationTester:54 - logging statement 6
16:04:45.194 [DEBUG] main c.a.ConfigurationTester:54 - logging statement 7
16:04:45.295 [DEBUG] main c.a.ConfigurationTester:54 - logging statement 8
16:04:45.395 [DEBUG] main c.a.ConfigurationTester:54 - logging statement 9
```

And this to james-server.log

```
16:04:45.502 [ERROR] main c.a.s.s.Bar:32 - error-level request
java.lang.Exception: test exception
    at chapters.appenders.sub.sample.Bar.subMethodToCreateRequest(Bar.java:32) [logback-examples-1.1.3.jar:na]
    at chapters.appenders.sub.sample.Bar.createLoggingRequest(Bar.java:27) [logback-examples-1.1.3.jar:na]
    at chapters.appenders.ConfigurationTester.main(ConfigurationTester.java:58) [logback-examples-1.1.3.jar:na]
```

Comment: I'm getting an error message for that test: `[ERROR] main c.a.s.s.Bar:32 - error-level request
java.lang.Exception: test exception`

Comment: lol I though it was an error too, but it's part of the [logging test](https://logback.qos.ch/xref/chapters/appenders/sub/sample/Bar.html).

Comment: Interesting. Anyway - when I will move JAMES-SERVER appender to the ROOT logger it will log to the `james-server.log` and `james.log` the same, but when moved back to log based on package name is not. I think it must be something related to Apache Common Logging as for Tomcat code when I will use SLF4J it works fine with logger name.

Comment: Did you add `additivity="false"` to the logger tag? Also, remove  `>> ./logs/james.log` from the command.

Comment: Finally I have got it to work. It looks like I need to keep `>> ./logs/james.log` and keep `immediateFlush` as `true` for JAMES-SERVER

Comment: `true`is the default so the same as removing it.